# Putnam and Beyond AM-GM help

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, contest-math

**From Putnam and Beyond:**

[image: rubalicious]

**The Solution is:**

[image: rubes abshire]

The only part I do NOT understand is how: $a_k + b_k = 1$ for every $k$? The problem just specifies nonnegative numbers?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $1 / \prod_{k = 1}^n (a_k + b_k)^{1/n}$. Replace $a_k / (a_k + b_k)$ by $\tilde{a}_k$, and $b_k / (a_k + b_k)$ by $\tilde{b}_k$.

Comment: How do you know that though @Macavity?

Comment: @Macavity , vocabulary especially. Scaling do you mean: $\lambda_k a_k + \lambda_k b_k$. He says for EVERY $k$. I am having a trouble fully understanding how $a_k + b_k = 1$ for ALL $k$?

Comment: Scaling means exactly that. So for e.g if you choose $\lambda_k =\dfrac1{a_k+b_k}$, the scaled sum will be $1$ for every $k$.

Comment: @Macavity? how will it be $1$ for every $k$?

Comment: Okay. Of course, that is also saying: $\frac{1 + 2}{1 + 2} = 1$ but why are you multiplying by $\lamba_k$ @Macavity?

Comment: @Macavity, also you said the scaled sum will be $1$? But we arent trying to find the scaled sum though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain one more time. Suppose we multiply every $a_k, b_k$ say with different scale $\lambda_k > 0$. You get
$$((\lambda_1 a_1) (\lambda_2 a_2)\dots (\lambda_n a_n))^{1/n}+((\lambda_1b_1)(\lambda b_2)\dots (\lambda_n b_n))^{1/n} \le \left((\lambda_1 a_1+ \lambda_1 b_1)(\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_2 b_2)\dots(\lambda_n a_n + \lambda_n b_n) \right)^{1/n}$$
Notice that $(\lambda_1\lambda_2\dots\lambda_n)^{1/n}$ is a factor of each term and hence will cancel off.  Essentially, as long as we can show the inequality for some choice of $\lambda_k$, it must hold true in general.

In particular, we may choose each $\lambda_k$ to be equal to $\dfrac1{a_k+b_k}$.  This is equivalent to restricting each $a_k, b_k$ to have a sum of $1$.  If the inequality is true for this case, it must hold for the general case as well.

Comment: I appreciate this very much which is why +1 and accept. $\lambda_1$ stays the same for $a_1$ and $b_1$ right? But you say $(\lamba_1 \lambda_2... \lambda_n)^{1/n}$ is a factor of each term. But how does it cancel out? Then okay you said: $\lambda_k = \frac{1}{a_k + b_k}$. So, $a_k + b_k = 1$ but did you require $\lambda_k$ to be an integer? But how can you change the inequalities with $\lambda$ in them?

Comment: Don't you think $(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \dots \lambda_n)^{1/n}$ is a factor of each term?

Comment: Ah - I see. $$((\lambda_1 a_1) (\lambda_2 a_2)\dots (\lambda_n a_n))^{1/n}+((\lambda_1b_1)(\lambda b_2)\dots (\lambda_n b_n))^{1/n}$$ Means: $$(a_1)(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3... \lambda_n \cdot (a_2).... \cdot (a_n)..$$ So you factor $$(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 ... \lambda_n)^{1/n}(a_1 + a_2 + .. + a_n + b_1 + b_2 + ... b_n)$$ Then on the RHS: $\lambda_1(a_1 + b_1) \cdot \lambda_2(a_2 + b_2)$ mmmm... Can you confirm my thoughts for the LHS, and tell me what to do with the RHS please? Thank you Macavity, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Absolutely no idea what you mean by all that above.

Comment: I edited the comment, thanks =)

Comment: Please, I almost got it, I just need some more help =)

Comment: That comment above has convinced me that you haven't.  You will need to try yourself or talk to someone at length.

Comment: would you mind chatting? Maybe some discussion can help? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21253/discussion-between-macavity-and-lebes).

Answer (score 0):

Start with simple. Let's assume n=2:
$A_2 = \large{(a_1a_2)}^{\frac{1}{2}} + \large{(b_1b_2)}^{\frac{1}{2}} \Rightarrow A^2_2 = (a_1a_2 + b_1b_2) + 2(a_1a_2b_1b_2)^{1/2}$

$B_2 = ((a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2))^{1/2} \Rightarrow B^2_2 = (a_1a_2 + b_1b_2) + (a_1b_2 +a_2b_1)$

We know that, $(a_1b_2 +a_2b_1) \ge 2(a_1a_2b_1b_2)^{1/2}$. ($A.M. \ge G.M.$)

Therefore, $B^2_2 \ge A^2_2 \; \Rightarrow \; B_2 > A_2$.

---

Now, all you have to do is generalize this proof.