# Assuming $a_k + b_k = 1$ (Putnam 2003)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, contest-math

I do not understand as I wrote in a previous question:

[image: juby]

solution:

[image: Ruby Abshire]

I see that we can scale:

$u_k$ but I do not understand why it is legal to say $a_k + b_k = 1$ what is $a_1 = 20$ and $b_1 = 1$ then $a_1 + b_1 \ne 1$?

Comment: Set $\tilde a_k := \frac1{a_k+b_k} a_k$ and $\tilde b_k := \frac1{a_k+b_k} b_k$.

Comment: @AlexR see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1152994/putnam-and-beyond-am-gm-help?noredirect=1#comment2356457_1152994 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155868/proof-for-scaling-homogeneous-inequalities

Comment: @Macavity, this is sort of a duplicate yes, but I know more than I did before and so I think a new question will be more beneficial to my understanding.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks for showing these. Voted to close.

Comment: @Lebes A new question just unnecessarily clutters the site. Instead, ask in a comment below an answer or ask a follow-up question linking to a specific answer asking for explanation of that answer.

Comment: @ALexR, comments for SMALL, that do not need a lot of clarification follow up questions. This isnt a followup, but rather a new one.

Comment: @AlexR, even if you vote to close, the question will still be on the site, you just dont want people to answer it.

Comment: @Lebes No. The answer to your question is that you pick a specific scaling factor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21256/discussion-between-alexr-and-lebes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to provide a rigorous (therefor less compact) solution based on the same proof:

WLOG $a_i, b_i > 0$, if not one product on the LHS vanishes and the RHS is the same as the RHS with bigger factors.

Let $\lambda_k := \frac1{a_k + b_k} > 0$. We multiply the inequality by $\Lambda := (\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \ldots \lambda_n)^{\frac1n} > 0$:

$$\begin{align*}
(a_1a_2 \ldots a_n)^{\frac1n} + (b_1b_2 \ldots b_n)^{\frac1n} & \le ((a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)\ldots(a_1+b_1))^{\frac1n} \\
\Leftrightarrow \Lambda (a_1a_2 \ldots a_n)^{\frac1n} + \Lambda (b_1b_2 \ldots b_n)^{\frac1n} & \le \Lambda ((a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)\ldots(a_1+b_1))^{\frac1n} \\
\Leftrightarrow (\lambda_1 a_1 \lambda_2 a_2 \ldots \lambda_n a_n)^{\frac1n} + (\lambda_1 b_1 \lambda_2 b_2 \ldots \lambda_n b_n)^{\frac1n} & \le (\lambda_1(a_1+b_1) \lambda_2(a_2+b_2) \ldots \lambda_n (a_n + b_n))^{\frac1n} \\
& = 1
\end{align*}$$
The last step uses $\lambda_i(a_i + b_i) = \frac1{a_i + b_i}(a_i + b_i) = 1$. Now we apply AM-GM to the list $(\lambda_ia_i)_{i=1}^n$ and to the list $(\lambda_i b_i)_{i=1}^n$ to get
$$\begin{align*}
(\lambda_1 a_1 \lambda_2 a_2 \ldots \lambda_n a_n)^{\frac1n} + (\lambda_1 b_1 \lambda_2 b_2 \ldots \lambda_n b_n)^{\frac1n} & \le \frac{\lambda_1a_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n a_n}n + \frac{\lambda_1 b_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n b_n}n \\
& = \frac1n(\lambda_1a_1 + \lambda_1 b_1 + \lambda_2 a_2 + \ldots + \lambda_n b_n) \\
& = \frac1n(\lambda_1 (a_1+b_1) + \lambda_2(a_2+b_2) + \ldots + \lambda_n(a_n+b_n))\\
& = \frac1n(1+\ldots+1) = \frac nn = 1
\end{align*}$$
As claimed.

Comment: (+1) I get all of it. This was the answer I was looking for. Well done. Did the solution from the book mean the same thing?

Comment: @Lebes Yes, they just left out the details for finding $\Lambda$.

Comment: So really this was all just simple multiplication?

Comment: @Lebes Yes, that's why people didn't understand your problem.

Comment: I see. Others were confusing me with scaling. If they had said just "multiplication," it would have been easier.

Comment: @Lebes The point is that "scaling" is synonymous to "multiplication of both sides by a constant".

Comment: I see. English got the best of me once again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $a_1=20,b_1=1$ then you can multiply then by common constant $1/21$ to get $a_1'=20/21,b_1'=1/21$. To see that we can so that without any loss in generality, note that if we multiply both sides of inequality in question $(a_1a_2...a_n)^{1/n}+(b_1b_2...b_n)^{1/n}\leq((a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)...(a_n+b_n))^{1/n}$ by $(1/21)^{1/n}$ then we get an equivalent inequality $(a_1'a_2...a_n)^{1/n}+(b_1'b_2...b_n)^{1/n}\leq((a_1'+b_1')(a_2+b_2)...(a_n+b_n))^{1/n}$. From the equivalence, we see that if the last inequality is true, so is the former one.

Now it should be simple enough to see that you can do the same to each pair $a_k,b_k$.

Comment: (+1), but $a_1' \ne a_1$ so ig you prove the inequality for $a_k'$ how is that the same as the original inequality?

Comment: The inequalities are equivalent, so proving one proves the other.

Comment: @Christoph, how are they equivalent?

Comment: Well, $x\le y$ is equivalent to $\lambda x \le \lambda y$ for any $\lambda>0$. Here $\lambda = \left(\frac{1}{21}\right)^{1/n}$.